# ¿Cómo hacer una pantalla que se adapte al tamaño que se le asigne?

Tags: vb.net, wpf

soy novato en esto del visual studio, y en esto de diseños,
tengo esta pantalla:

```
    <StackPanel Margin="227,0,10,668">
        <materialDesign:Card 
                    materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth1" 
                    Height="62" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Background="White"
                    Margin="3,3,0,3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="776"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Margin="0,59,798,20">
        <materialDesign:Card 
                    materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Height="663" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Width="215" 
                    Background="White"
                    Margin="3,3,3,3">
            <TreeView
             Grid.Column="0"
             MinWidth="220">
                <TextBlock FontStretch="SemiExpanded" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold" IsEnabled="False">Menú Principal</TextBlock>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Cargar Catálogos" IsExpanded="False">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Proveedores"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Artículos"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Sucursales"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Equivalencias"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Sustitutos"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Alternos"/>
                </TreeViewItem>

                <TreeViewItem Header="Cargar Datos" IsExpanded="False">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Existencias"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Ventas"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Mercancía en tránsito"/>
                </TreeViewItem>

                <TreeViewItem Header="Equilibrar Existencias"/>

                <TreeViewItem Header="Generar Proyecciones"/>

                <TreeViewItem Header="Otros" IsExpanded="False">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Excluir Artículos"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Excluir Facturas"/>
                </TreeViewItem>

                <TreeViewItem Header="Ver Registros" IsExpanded="False">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Artículo"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Proveedor"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Sucursal"/>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeView>
        </materialDesign:Card>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Margin="227,106,1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="356">
        <materialDesign:Card x:Name="crdGrafica"
                    Margin="3,3,0,3"
                    Padding="8" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="339.531" materialDesign:ShadowAssist.ShadowDepth="Depth2">
            <materialDesign:Card.LayoutTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </materialDesign:Card.LayoutTransform>
        </materialDesign:Card>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Margin="227,512,599,101" Width="190">
        <materialDesign:Card
                Margin="4,4,10,0" Height="94">
            <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.495,0.739" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="12" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="16" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Margin="0,8,8,8"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Orientation="Horizontal" Width="30"/>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="63,23,10,13" Grid.Row="1"><Run Text="Clientes"/></TextBlock>
                <Button x:Name="cmdClientes"
                        Padding="2,0,2,0"
                        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolButton}" Margin="1,1,0,1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="Auto" Content="" Grid.RowSpan="3" Click="Button_Click">
                    <Button.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="-0.148"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Button.RenderTransform>
                </Button>
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Account" Margin="9,15,0,0" Height="34" Width="51" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </materialDesign:Card>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Margin="425,512,401,101" Width="190">
        <materialDesign:Card
                Margin="4,4,10,0" Height="94">
            <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.495,0.739" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="12" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="16" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Margin="0,8,8,8"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Orientation="Horizontal" Width="30"/>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="63,23,10,13" Grid.Row="1"><Run Text="Proveedores"/></TextBlock>
                <Button x:Name="cmdProveedores"
                        Padding="2,0,2,0"
                        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolButton}" Margin="1,1,0,1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="Auto" Content="" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                    <Button.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="-0.148"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Button.RenderTransform>
                </Button>
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="TruckDelivery" Margin="9,15,0,0" Height="34" Width="51" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </materialDesign:Card>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Margin="626,512,200,101" Width="190">
        <materialDesign:Card
                Margin="4,4,10,0" Height="94">
            <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.495,0.739" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="12" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="16" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Margin="0,8,8,8"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Orientation="Horizontal" Width="30"/>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="63,23,10,13" Grid.Row="1"><Run Text="Ventas"/></TextBlock>
                <Button
                        Padding="2,0,2,0"
                        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolButton}" Margin="1,1,0,1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="Auto" Content="" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                    <Button.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="-0.148"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Button.RenderTransform>
                </Button>
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Sale" Margin="9,15,0,0" Height="34" Width="51" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </materialDesign:Card>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Margin="827,512,-1,101" Width="190">
        <materialDesign:Card
                Margin="4,4,10,0" Height="94">
            <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.495,0.739" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="12" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="16" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Margin="0,8,8,8"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Orientation="Horizontal" Width="30"/>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Margin="63,23,10,13" Grid.Row="1"><Run Text="Pendientes"/></TextBlock>
                <Button
                        Padding="2,0,2,0"
                        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignToolButton}" Margin="1,1,0,1" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="Auto" Content="" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                    <Button.RenderTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform/>
                            <SkewTransform/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="-0.148"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </Button.RenderTransform>
                </Button>
                <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Alarm" Margin="9,15,0,0" Height="34" Width="51" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </materialDesign:Card>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Tengo el paquete de Material de [Material Design in XAML](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/).
Cuando cambió el tamaño de la pantalla, todos mis botones, y mis controles desaparecen, y otros se estiran; Y necesito que la pantalla sea responsiva, osea que se adapten al tamaño de la pantalla.

Comment: porque usas un stack panel, y no un dock panel para acomodar las cosas y grillas para darles posiciones en las pantallas??

Comment: Estoy leyendo y tratando de usar DockPanel, y me está saliendo mejor.

Comment: mas que eso, sin ver tu pantalla y como deberia ir quedando es dificil darte mas ayuda..

Comment: (https://ibb.co/cytHnb) Aqui está la imágen

Comment: si vas a agregar informacion, por favor usa el boton [edit] y agrega la informacion a la pregunta.. tambien lo que hayas cambiado/probado hasta ahora..